# How to store array data into database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have some JSON data; I decode that JSON data into an array, now I need to save the link column, id column and username column into my database table (the table name may be the product). So how to insert/save this column into the database in Laravel? My single node array structure format is below.

```js
   {
        0 => {
          +"attribution": null
          +"tags": array:11 
          +"type": "image"
          +"location": null
          +"filter": "Normal"
          +"created_time": ""
          +"link": "https://www.url.com/p/myimage1/"
          +"id": "4354"
          +"user": {
            +"username": "user"
            +"profile_picture": "https://mypic.jpg"
            +"id": "224"
            +"full_name": ""
          }
        }
       
        }
```

Comment: What is the issue? 1) Create a class object 2) set object property value 3) save object.

Comment: Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-inserts)

Comment: @RaviHirani the link which you given according to this create a new record in the database,but my problem is different,i already have array data i need to save this data into my data base product  table.

Comment: @raj: in that case you need to find record by PK. see this link:- Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question. Also, you need to add the logic of your app for a better answer. Except for a special need you should use normal columns in relational database tables: as id, tags, type, location etc If you really need to save the monster, loop through the array (foreach) and create a smaller array with data you need, you may save the result array as string on a text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to save original json data or convert array to json with `->toJson()` or `json_encode()` and save it to a DB as Json data:

```
$table->json('options'); // JSON equivalent for the database.
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations

Answer (score 1):

you can use `toJson()` method for it as below:

```
$table->toJson('options');
```